# How to get httponly cookies from a Java client?

Tags: java, http, cookies

how to get httponly cookies? What tools should I use org.apache.http or jsoup, may be url connection... please anybody give me example. I tryed to get cookies using jsoup, but jsoup doesn't return httponly cookies.
Thanks!!!

Comment: We need a bit more information - how are you trying to do this?  Is a servlet environment like Tomcat or just a java program.  Do you have any code that you could share?

Comment: apache http should be able to simple read the `Set-Cookie` header. No idea about JSOUP bit it can probably do the same. Whether it's `HttpOnly` or not is basically irrelevant outside of browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `java.net.CookieHandler`, referenced at: [Java Cookie Handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/)

As an example taken directly from http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html:

> Retrieving cookies from a response:

Open a `java.net.URLConnection` to the server:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.hccp.org/cookieTest.jsp");
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.connect();
```

Loop through response headers looking for cookies:
Since a server may set multiple cookies in a single request, we will need to loop through the response headers, looking for all headers named "Set-Cookie".

```
String headerName=null;
for (int i=1; (headerName = uc.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
    if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
    String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);               
    ...
```

Extract cookie name and value from cookie string:
The string returned by the getHeaderField(int index) method is a series of name=value separated by semi-colons (;). The first name/value pairing is actual data string we are interested in (i.e. "sessionId=0949eeee22222rtg" or "userId=igbrown"), the subsequent name/value pairings are meta-information that we would use to manage the storage of the cookie (when it expires, etc.).

```
cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
```

This is basically it. We now have the cookie name (`cookieName`) and the cookie value (`cookieValue`).

Comment: Code doesn't work.  headerName doesn't equal "Set-Cookie". But CookieHandler realy works! I found example here [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/cookie_handling_in_java_se)

Answer (score 0):

> *please anybody give me example*

Here is one with Jsoup.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Response response;
try {
    response = Jsoup //
            .connect("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set?http-only-cookie=test;%20httponly") //
            .ignoreContentType(true) //
            .execute();

    System.out.println(response.cookies());
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
{http-only-cookie="test\073 httponly"}
```